# Auto find and replace app for Mac

Tags: mac, code, coda

So I am making a website, and I want to replace code amongst many files at the same time, rather than doing it individually which would take an extremely long time. I am currently using codas find and replace but the small input box makes this hard and codas find and replace feature is not very advanced.

Is there any separate apps that are dedicated to this? any other tips etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coda has a very advanced search/replace functionality. Select *Edit » Find » Find in Files*.

[image]

You notice the triangle drag thingy on the lower right? And the button with dropdown symbol to the left?

[image]

---

There you go: Two clicks and you have an arbitrarily large search box and more regexp option syntax choices than you possibly can learn.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) for my HTML. While it's not a dedicated application, it is free (available from Mac App Store) and it does a good Search & Replace.

Answer (score 0):

sed, if you're comfortable with the terminal.  'man sed' for more information.  From the man file for sed:

> The sed utility reads the specified files, or the standard input if no files
>        are specified, modifying the input as specified by a list of commands.  The
>        input is then written to the standard output.